# Who sizes the backlog stories

Tags: scrum

Does the product owner actually vote on the size of the story in Scrum or is it just Dev/QA?

I was wondering, because it does not really seem like having the product owner vote is productive.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "classic" scrum, the team decides on the estimates and commitments of a story without the PO. The story in the backlog is discussed by the team and the PO and then agreed upon by the team.

EDIT : as nuqqsa and xsAce pointed out, the presence of the PO can be helpful during the estimation session, as he can help clarify the exact requirements and thus make the estimation more precise, but he does not take part in the actual estimating.

Comment: I think it's OK if the PO attend the estimation process. then he can help if the team need more details to properly estimate one of the story.

Comment: The PO, while not participating in the estimation itself, needs to be there during the planning session for he is responsible to clarify any doubts the team may have about the stories

Comment: @nuqqsa you're right, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 3):

The Team (Dev/QA in your question, but anyone who's committing to the Team's iteration delivery (designers, documentation writers are some I've seen) comes to a consensus on the size of each story, and the overall size that can fit into the iteration.

Scrum Teams generally use a 2-phase planning meeting; discussing prioritized stories with the PO, estimating them (which may reveal inconsistent understanding by Team members and/or the PO) using a non-timebased unit (story points, t-shirt sizes, etc.), and then when an agreement has been reached about what will fit into the iteration, breaking the stories down into tasks, and estimating them in the 2nd phase. (It's permissible to renegotiate the iteration commitment if there is dissonance between the the 1st and 2nd phase estimates.)

Hopefully, instead of 'voting' (estimate with the most votes wins), the Team is coming to a common consensus of understanding and effort, so that everyone can commit equally.  If it comes down to two next-to-each-other-estimates-on-the-scale-being-used that the Team can't come to a complete consensus on, the larger one wins.

There is an inherent conflict-of-interest with the PO participating in the estimation process.  If s/he really thinks the Team's estimate is out-of-whack, then perhaps they do not share the same understanding of what's being asked for, and a few minutes should be spent gaining additional clarity.

Remember the 3Cs of the User Story 'card' -- Card, Conversation, Confirmation. The Card is a promise of a Conversation between the PO and the Team. The PO absolutely needs to be part of that Conversation (can't have it w/o them!), and the PO and Team need to understand and agree upon the Confirmation (acceptance tests) needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Dev/QA decides on the size of story and the associated estimates. Product owner shares the prioritized product backlog with the team and the team decides which items they can complete within the current sprint.